# How do I see if my GPU supports Audio through DVI (via HDMI Adapter)

Tags: audio, graphics-card, hdmi, dvi

I am trying to connect my TV to my [GTX 1080](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01GAI64GO) Graphics Card.

Would I be able to use a [DVI to HDMI Female](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009YCASK2) adapter with a HDMI cable and have audio go through the cable?

I know some Graphics Cards can have audio go through the DVI Port if there is an DVI-HDMI adapter plugged in but how can I know for sure short of buying the adapter and cable and testing it out

Comment: I cannot answer for sure, but I am fairly certain that DVI and HDMI are electrically compatible and the audio is "bundled" with the video on the same wires. A quick check of my Nvidia 950 panel shows "no audio capable display" under the "set up digital audio" for both DVI and HDMI, so you should at least check to see if that display will respond to a "PnP/capabilities" query.

Comment: The card has an HDMI port, does the TV?, why are you using the gender changer?

Comment: @Moab Yes it does but the HDMI is being used by a HTC Vive. The 3x DP are being used by 3x monitors. I want DVI to HDMI Female so I can then run a 50' long HDMI cable.

Comment: I would contact EVGA support and ask them...  http://www.evga.com/support/custsupp.asp